# Where can I find the config file that points to my JRE?

Tags: java

I have the following method that used to be working fine :

```
  private static boolean exec(String command,boolean printResults,boolean wait)
  {
    String Command_List[],Command_Array[]=command.split(" ");
    Process p;

    Result_String="";
    Result_String_With_System_Prompt="";

    try
    {
      Command_List=new String[Command_Array.length+2];
      Command_List[0]="cmd";
      Command_List[1]="/c";
      for (int i=0;i<Command_Array.length;i++) Command_List[i+2]=Command_Array[i];

      System.out.println("Command_List = "+Arrays.toString(Command_List));
      ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(Command_List);  // new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","java","-version");

      pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
      p=pb.start();

      // Print the output. Since we read until there is no more input,this causes us to wait until the process is completed
      if (printResults)
      {
        BufferedInputStream buffer=new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader command_Result=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buffer));

        while ((Last_String=command_Result.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(Last_String);
            Result_String+=Last_String+"\n";
            Result_String_With_System_Prompt+=Last_String+"\n"+System_Prompt;
         }
         command_Result.close();
      }
  }
  catch (Exception e) { ... }
}
```

It worked fine until this morning, I saw a dialog window from Oracle saying Oracle JDK is not longer free ... asking me if I want to update or not, so I said no, and it uninstalled my old versions of Java [ JRE ], then I installed the free OpenJdk 12 by myself, and I verified by opening a command line window and typed "java -version", I got the following output :

```
C:\Users\USER>java -version
openjdk version "12" 2019-03-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 12+33)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 12+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So after that I run my above method, but I got the following error message :

```
Command_List = [cmd, /c, java, -jar, C:/Dir_ProGuard/proguard6.0.3/lib/proguard.jar, @C:/Dir_Run_ProGuard/XYZ.pro, -verbose]
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Then I went to System control panel to check my classpath, none of them points to jre1.8.0_91, so my question is where is this "jre1.8.0_91" info saved in a config file, so I can go there and update it to my latest JRE 12 ?

Comment: Cool, a bug on the Oracle uninstaller :-(. It'$ window$ so it could be a registry record, not a config file.

Comment: Make sure your system PATH variable has your OpenJDK path as the first in the list that points to anything "java related". Double-check your %java_home% environment variable, and, if you're using an IDE (eclipse, intelliJ, netbeans, etc), make sure you've switched the build environment over to JDK12  (There are no more JREs as far as I know, going forward from Java~10ish)

Comment: Oracle JDK is no longer free ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a simple answer, yet I didn't realize, now after I re-started the Windows, it is running correctly. So just need a re-boot !